# a commutative type diagram

Tags: tikz-arrows, commutative-diagrams

Could anyone tell me how can I draw such a diagram? I was looking from here.

http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf

Thanks.

I tried

```
$
\begin{tikzcd}
\text{A} \arrow[r] \arrow[d] & \text{D} \arrow[d] \\
\text{B}\arrow[r] & \text{B}
\end{tikzcd}
$
```

[image: commutative]

Comment: What you try so far? In manual are many diagram examples, there you can find listed available tips. for dashed you can use option `dashed` etc.

Comment: Please consider adding a full, minimum working example (MWE) document to your question, from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` that contains your current "nearest" effort towards a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A starting point:

```
\documentclass[margin=3.1415692mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, bending}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=13mm, row sep=13mm,
               bend angle=20]
IS  \ar[rr,Leftrightarrow, blue]
    \ar[rd, Rightarrow, bend right, "\text{not}" description, red]  
    \ar[dd, Rightarrow, bend right, "\text{not}" description]  
        &   &   CD  \ar[dd, Rightarrow,  bend left, "\text{not}" description, red]  
                    \ar[dl, Rightarrow, bend right, "\text{not}" description, red]\\
        & ECD   \ar[ul, Rightarrow, bend right, dashed, blue] 
                \ar[ru, Rightarrow, green]
                \ar[ld, Leftrightarrow, dashed, blue]  
                \ar[rd, Leftrightarrow, dotted, blue]
            &                                   \\
EIS \ar[uu, Rightarrow, green]
    \ar[rr, green, Leftrightarrow]
       &   &   CD \ar[uu, Rightarrow, dotted, blue]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For repeating lengthy set of keys one may introduce shortcuts. It is also an attempt to recreate the special pattern of the blue arrows on the bottom right.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\colorlet{mgreen}{green!70!black}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=3em,column sep=3em,
    rnot/.style={Rightarrow,red,"\text{not}" {description}},
    bd/.style={preaction={draw,blue,line width=1.6pt,-,shorten >=2.2pt,shorten
    <=2.2pt},
    blue,dashed}
    ]
\text{IS} \arrow[rr,Leftrightarrow,blue,dashed] 
\arrow[dd,bend right,rnot] 
\arrow[dr,bend right=15,rnot] 
& & \text{CD}
\arrow[dd,bend left,rnot] 
\arrow[dl,bend left=15,rnot] 
\\
&\text{EIS}  
\arrow[ul,Rightarrow,blue,dashed,bend right=15]
\arrow[ur,Rightarrow,mgreen,bend left=15]
&\\
\text{EIS} \arrow[uu,Rightarrow,mgreen]
\arrow[ur,Leftrightarrow,blue,dashed]
\arrow[rr,Leftrightarrow,mgreen] 
& & \text{CA} \arrow[ul,Leftrightarrow,bd]
\arrow[uu,Rightarrow,bd]\\
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]